# "Surely" vs. "Certainly"

Tags: difference, meaning

> "The high oil prices are **surely** not wholesome for the economy." 
>   —Axel Weber.

Does Axel Weber correctly use **surely** in his statement?

How does the meaning of that quote change replacing **surely** with **certainly**?

I'm asking because, as far as I understand, **surely** does not imply that something is true, instead **certainly** does. So I would conclude that Axel Weber is unsure of what he stated, which is at least strange if not absurd.

Can anybody shed a bit of light on this matter?

Comment: _Surely_, _certainly_, and _assuredly_ are all synonyms that are used to express confidence; however, of these, only [_surely_](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A5t5_O8hdA) can set up the "Stop calling me Shirley" joke. "Surely the high oil prices aren't good for the economy." "On the contrary, they are good – and stop calling me Shirley."

Comment: @J.R.: It's true puns based on *certainly* are thin on the ground - but they're [Sir Tanely not unknown](http://forums.2000adonline.com/index.php?topic=18986.0)

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing wrong with the cited usage. In this precise context, *surely* and *certainly* mean exactly the same thing *(definitely, unquestionably)*.

In some other contexts, there's often a tendency to use *surely* where the speaker is "reasonably" sure of something, but recognises the possibility he might be mistaken. Or even that he *already recognises* that some unlikely scenario may indeed be the case...

> *"You're **surely** not going to refuse to pay the restaurant bill just because there was a fly in the soup!"*

...strongly implies that although the speaker thinks refusing to pay is unreasonable, they do in fact think this is what's likely to happen. Using *certainly* there implies payment will definitely be made - and if necessary the speaker will take steps to impose this outcome.

Note that my example sentence could reasonably be spoken with "question" intonation, and could thus be terminated by a question mark in the written form. This would be far less likely using *certainly*. It's not that *sure* is less "definite" than *certain* - but note [what thefreedictionary says](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/to+be+sure)...

> **Sure** and **certain** are frequently used interchangeably; *sure*, however, is the more subjective term, whereas *certain* may imply belief based on experience or evidence.

...which in the context of my example means *surely* can be seen as focusing on the speaker's *subjective opinion* (he thinks the bill *should* be paid), where *certainly* focuses on the speaker's *knowledge* (that the bill *will* be paid, regardless of any arguments involving the unwanted fly).

Answer (score 5):

The word **surely** can be used when trying persuade someone; to me it has a sense of a question, inviting someone to agree, like this:

> The high oil prices are **surely** not wholesome for the economy, don't you agree?

The word **certainly** to me has more of a sense of authority and finality, like this:

> The high oil prices are **certainly** not wholesome for the economy, how could you think otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

"Surely" often has a connotation of mock (or even real) disbelief that anything other than stated could be possible or believed. Examples: "Surely you jest!" (a line from a 1960's era American TV show that has variously been falsely ascribed to Shakespeare and Poe)
And more recently, from the 1980's comedy movie "Airplane!" (that's the origin of the "and don't call me Shirley" jokes people allude to) it's used extensively for the joke and to express disbelief.

This is an instance of where two words are so close in basic meaning that choosing between them becomes more a matter of art, preference, and connotation rather than overt meaning.

There are few instances where you would be incorrect to switch out the two words, but "surely" seems to be far more commonly used to convey that less-than-obvious sly connotation.

The connotation of "certain" is more commonly that the speaker believes he has some clear evidence or experience that is particularly convincing, where as "surely" is more commonly used in cases where the speaker believes something to be particularly obvious or axiomatic. After all, could higher oil prices really be expected to boost the economy?